# DuplicateMappingException Table [] contains physical column name [] referred to by multiple logical column names: [_id], [Id]

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, lombok

I am rewriting a project and I have a build issue.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Table [language] contains physical column name [person_id] referred to by multiple logical column names: [person_id], [personId]
```

where

```
@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@IdClass(LanguagePK.class)
@Table(name = "language")
public class Language {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "person_id")
    private int personId;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "position")
    private int position;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "language_name")
    private String languageNameVal;
    @Column(name = "language_level")
    private String languageLevelVal;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, insertable = false,updatable = false)
    @JsonBackReference(value = "languages")
    private Person person;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "language_name", referencedColumnName = "name", nullable = false, insertable = false,updatable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private LanguageName languageName;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "language_level", referencedColumnName = "level", nullable = false, insertable = false,updatable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private LanguageLevel languageLevel;
}
```

and

```
@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

@JsonManagedReference(value = "languages")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private Set<Language> languages;
```

I use

- hibernate v. 5.4.13.Final
- spring-boot v. 2.2.5.RELEASE
- gradle
- java 1.8
- lombok

The changes are very minor like before I was using maven, SessionFactory for hibernate, traditional getters and setter.

I saw some similar issues where NamingStrategy was a problem during migration between hibernate 4 and 5, but this code works on the first project where hiberante is 5.4.10.Final.

I like IdClass because I have access to personId as primitive value and don't have to load data from object person.

I saw similar issues without `insertable = false,updatable = false` but I have it...

Simmilar issue found [here](https://qiita.com/talesleaves/items/7977274564678970c5d3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution**

The issue was on the access strategy field vs property access.

In the previous project, everything was with property-based access, but after I have added lombok the class `Language` was field-based access.

The class `LanguagePK` was

```
public class LanguagePK implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int personId;
    private int position;
    private String languageNameVal;

    @Column(name = "person_id")
    @Id
    public int getPersonId() {
        return personId;
    }

    public void setPersonId(int personId) {
        this.personId = personId;
    }

    @Column(name = "position")
    @Id
    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    @Column(name = "language_name")
    @Id
    public String getLanguageNameVal() {
        return languageNameVal;
    }

    public void setLanguageNameVal(String languageNameVal) {
        this.languageNameVal = languageNameVal;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        LanguagePK that = (LanguagePK) o;

        if (personId != that.personId) return false;
        if (position != that.position) return false;
        if (languageNameVal != null ? !languageNameVal.equals(that.languageNameVal) : that.languageNameVal != null)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = personId;
        result = 31 * result + position;
        result = 31 * result + (languageNameVal != null ? languageNameVal.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

It's enough and works

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class EducationPK implements Serializable {
    private int personId;
    private int position;
}
```